# Attribute error? Pyspark dataframe() error

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following error in my code :

> NonRetryableError: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute
>   'dataframe'

Does anyone know what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have an object of type `Dataframe`, and you are trying to call the attribute `dataframe` which does not exist.

Comment: Hello Steven thank you for you answer, but i don't think that's the error.

Comment: @benji6482 That is literally what is written in your error !